# Saving values from arraylist to txt C#

Tags: c#, wpf, arraylist

How to save everything from ArrayList to .txt file in c#, then on starting WPF application load it?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? And `ArrayList` in 2013? Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Per the comment by Soner, using the strongly typed collection gives you serialization built-in to .net since version 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void SaveArray()
    {
        ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
        myArray.Add("First");
        myArray.Add("Second");
        myArray.Add("Third");
        myArray.Add("and more");

        StreamWriter sw= File.CreateText(@"C:\file.txt");
        foreach (string item in myArray)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(item);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

and you shouldn't use arraylist not because its 2013 ,but because arraylist boxing each item in the array, where List store the type also.

this cost less in memory use.

Comment: Performance-wise...Would you not consider a StringBuilder and write the whole shebang out in one go using File.WriteAllText?

Comment: and then you would use for each on the array anyway. so you will hold 2 references instead of one.

Comment: It common to use StringBuilder when you need to append a large string data. (I think more then 256 chars)